# Passing data to delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this use case where a model object (e.g. class User) has few methods.

Some of the methods in the class require authentication (e.g. getProfile, getFriends,...).

```
   class User{

          var loginDelegate:LoginDelegate

          func getProfile{
              HTTPAsync.getProfile(payload){response in 
                     if response.status == 401 {
                           login(delegate)
                      }
               }


          func getFriends{
                 //similar code as above
                        login(delegate)
          }
```

Once, user is successfully logged in, I want to call respective functions (getFriends, getProfile, whichever invoked login).

I have been thinking to use delegate pattern. But since my class (user) has multiple methods that require login,  I need to pass some data to delegate, which must be read after user is logged in to call the appropriate method.

I am new to Swift, and was wondering if I am going in the right path. Is there any other obvious way to achieve this pretty common problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, use a Url whiteList to solve this problem,
For example, the Url inside the user authentication interface which contains "/users/" this string (or other strings), when the user is not logged in and used a request for such a Url to send out a notification, by a unified class to receive this notification,then Pop up Login box

Answer (score 0):

***I am new to Swift, and was wondering if I am going in the right path. Is there any other obvious way to achieve this pretty common problem.***

Yes there are a couple of ways you might choose to solve this. e

1. Define getter methods on your delegate protocol, if it is not your own delegate protocol you can use an [extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) to extend it's functionality.
2. Create an [Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) as an instance variable so you can set an enumeration value with in the login method that your other methods can access after the login method finishes.
3. Change the login method to accept more parameters and returns a value\object.

   For example:

   `login(delegate: LoginDelegate, dictionaryOfOtherStuff: [String :AnyObject]?) -> (value_1: String, value_2 : [int])`

I can only give an example since you have not stated exactly what needs to be available after the login method is called.